# Contact form width issue

Tags: html, css

My contact form is looking how it is supposed to in desktop and tablet mode. However, when I switch my browser to mobile the email input in slightly shorter than the name input and the text box. What is causing this issue?

```css
#formsec{
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
}
#worktogether{
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 font-size:50px;
 margin-top:60px;
 font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
}

form {
 max-width:1200px;
 margin: 0 auto 50px;     
}

input, textarea {
 border: 3px solid #69EAF5;
 width:100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:10px;
}

label{
 display:block;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

span{
 display:block;
 color:white;
 font-size:20px;
}

.contact-info-group label{
 width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 float:left;
}

.contact-info-group label:nth-child(1){
 
}

.contact-info-group label:nth-child(2){
 padding-left:15px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus{
 outline: none;
    border-color:#008a91;
}

textarea{
 height:400px;
}

.button-wrap{
 margin-left:67%;
 width:33%;
}

[type="submit"]{
 background:#097784;
 border-color:#097784;
 color:white;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){

 .contact-info-group label{
 width: 100%;

box-sizing: border-box;
 float:left; 
 
 }
}
```

```html
<section id="formsec">
 <h3 id="worktogether">Let's Work Together</h3>
 
 <form id="form2" action="FormToEmail.php" methods="POST">
  <div class="contact-info-group">
  <label><span>Your Name</span>
  <input type="text" name="text"></label>
  
  <label><span>Your Email</span>
  <input type="email" name="_replyto"></label>
   </div>
   
 <label><span>How Can I Help:</span>  
  <textarea name="message"></textarea></label>
 

<input class="button-wrap" name="submit_to_programmer" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 15px padding for desktop, which needs to be removed for mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
   .contact-info-group label:nth-child(2) {
      padding-left:0px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to override the padding set for the second child in media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .contact-info-group label:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help.!